# How exactly does Typescript's generic type alias Exclude<T,U> work?

Tags: typescript

The generic type alias is defined as follows: `type Exclude<T,U> = T extends U ? never : T`. How does this definition yield a type that excludes all the properties from `T` that are assignable to `U`? According to the my interpretation, if `T` doesn't extend `U`, the given type `T` should be yielded. For example, in this example: `type T0 = Exclude<"a" | "b" | "c", "a">` it should return the union type `"a" | "b" | "c"`, because it is the `T` in the definition of `Exclude`. Can someone explain in detail how the definition works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional types are [distributive](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), that is

```
Exclude<"a"|"b"|"c", "a">
```

is translated to

```
"a" extends "a" ? never : "a" |
"b" extends "a" ? never : "b" |
"c" extends "a" ? never : "c"
```

which gives `never | "b" | "c"` or just `"b" | "c"`

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now, I've missed that part of the TS documentation.